# Xamarin iOS: Barcode scanning interval

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I have implemented a barcode scanner in my app successfully using AVFoundation and a AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate, however after the initial barcode is scanned it becomes increasingly difficult for the app to recognize (or process) another barcode. I have a feeling that it has to do with the amount of MetadataFound calls and am not sure if there is a minimum interval I can put on recognizing a barcode from the camera.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to start another scan meanwhile?